# Table is not appended with ajax data instead in browser it's showing the json array

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

```
 <script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#btnClick').click(function () {
            $.ajax({
                url: '/jQueryPratice/HandleJsonArray',
                dataType: 'json',
                method: 'post',
                success: function (data) {
                    var roleTable = $('#tblRole tbody');
                    $(data).each(function (index, role) {
                        roleTable.append('<tr><td>' + role.RoleDescription + '</td><td>' + role.RoleShortDescription + '</td></tr>')
                    });
                }
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

and in view

```
<body>
<hr />
<input type="button" value="Click" id="btnClick" />
<br /><br />
    <table id="tblRole" border="1">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>
                    RoleDescription
                </th>
                <th>
                    RoleShortDescription
                </th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody></tbody>
    </table>
```

now I want to append the table when the click button is click. I am getting data from the call but it is not binding the data instead on browser  I am getting the pure jaon array. what should i do to bind the array with the table?

Comment: could you show the data which you get from ajax?

Comment: [{"RoleID":1,"RoleDescription":"Administrative User","RoleShortDescription":"ADMIN","InsertUserId":0},{"RoleID":2,"RoleDescription":"Human Resources User","RoleShortDescription":"HR","InsertUserId":0},{"RoleID":3,"RoleDescription":"General User","RoleShortDescription":"GEN","InsertUserId":0},{"RoleID":4,"RoleDescription":"Operative User","RoleShortDescription":"OPERATOR","InsertUserId":0},{"RoleID":5,"RoleDescription":"Ajaira User","RoleShortDescription":"FALTU","InsertUserId":0},{"RoleID":6,"RoleDescription":"New User","RoleShortDescription":"NEW","InsertUserId":0}

Comment: You should  update your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe You are returning the data directly from the ajax call method to the browser. try receive data to a view first then append it.

```
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }
```

create your table and button in this view. Then use another action method to return your collection like that

```
public ActionResult HandleJsonArray()
    {
        //get roles
        return Json(roles, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

Hope it will work for you.

Comment: can you be more specific please?

Comment: which frameWork you are using?

Comment: i have updated my answer. let me know if it works or not

Answer (score 0):

I just needed to pass the json list to a view instead of return directly like

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    return View();
}
public ActionResult HandleJsonArray()
{
    //get roles
    return Json(roles, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```